# Storing data from txt file with whitespaces with readLine

Tags: java, arraylist, whitespace, readline

I'm trying to write a code that reads from a txt information about a person and stores it in variables, then uses the variables to create a contact and then add that contact to an ArrayList. When I execute the program it says that it can't parse the email, like its trying to store the email as if it was the date. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
    try
    {
        File file = new File(prop.getProperty("path"));
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        String name, lastName, mail;
        Date birthDate;

        String line; 
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null) 
        { 
            if (!line.trim().equals("")) 
            { 
                name = br.readLine(); 
                lastName = br.readLine(); 
                
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
                birthDate = format.parse(br.readLine()); 
                
                mail = br.readLine(); 
                
                Contacto contacto = new Contacto(name, lastName, birthDate, mail); 
                gestor.addContact(contacto);
            }
        }
    }
        
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ive also tried this, but it stores the contact twice:

```
String birth; 
while((name = br.readLine())!= null && (lastName = br.readLine())!= null && (birth = br.readLine())!= null && (mail = br.readLine())!= null)
{ 
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    birthDate = format.parse(birth); 
                
    Contacto contacto = new Contacto(name, lastName, birthDate, mail); 
        gestor.addContact(contacto); 
}
```

The txt file is structured like this:

```
Name 
LastName1 LastName2 
1970-01-01 
sample@mail.es
```

Comment: The [readLine documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) states `Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.` I find it weird for you to have the described behavior.

Comment: A space meaning an empty line? If that's the case just call `readLine` until the line read line is not empty and only then assign it to your field.

Comment: I didnt understand the error correctly. When I execute the program it says that it can't parse the email, like its trying to store the email as if it was the date. I really dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be something like :

```
        try {
            File file = new File("/Users/soumyabratakole/test/test");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            String name=null;
            String lastName1=null;
            String lastName2=null;
            Date birthDate=null;
            String email=null;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            int i=0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.trim().equals("")){
                    int j =i%5;
                    i ++;
                    switch (j){
                        case 0:
                            name = line;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            lastName1 = line;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            lastName2 = line;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            birthDate = format.parse(line);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            email = line;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (j == 4){
                        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Lastname " + lastName1 + " " + lastName2 + ", BDay " + birthDate + ", Email " + email);
//Other operations
                Contacto contacto = new Contacto(name, lastName1, birthDate, mail); 
                gestor.addContact(contacto);


                    }


                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I just tried it but it still says that the email is an unparseable date.

Comment: Your modified code and sample data from your file would be helpful.

Comment: sorry i changed it because if (!line.trim().equals("")) didn't work and didn't change it back before i commented. The txt has Name / both Last Names / Birthdate / Email, in different lines, the comment changes the format.